# Android: Not receiving any broadcasted intents

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, broadcastreceiver

I have been having problems changing all refernce to this custom intent. Aka I change the name and it no longer registers. However, more concerningly, it seems I cant get any broadcasted intents! (Except `APPWIDGET_UPDATE`).

```
<receiver android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetProvider" 
            android:label="@string/widget1name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
         <!-- <action android:name="com.eightbitcloud.example.widget.8BITCLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE" />  -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />

     </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget1_info" />
</receiver>
```

With code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received intent " + intent.getAction());
```

The only one that fires is Appwidget_update.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was to do with the my `onEnabled()` event, creating an alarmManager that sends the given intent again and again.

By changing what I was recieving, I obviously filter out the old one.

However what I failed to see, was that Eclipse was replacing my widget when I ran new code, but it never re-fires onEnabled again.

So the old intent was still firing, and being filtered, as opposed to my new named intent.

Restarting the phone, and/or removing the widgets and replacing them should do the trick (So `OnEnabled()` is fired again)

Answer (score 2):

Some broadcast events are only fired if you register a receiver in code. Try to add this to your onCreate:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Log.e("test","screen changed!!!");
        }
}, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
```

Comment: I heard this from commonware too in one of his answers. However, you cant register recievers from a reciever. Im trying to do this for a widget. `intentreceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents`. +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the default category in the intent filter:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but Ive already tried this, and the docs say `In principle, therefore, an Intent object with no categories should always pass this test, regardless of what's in the filter.` It will only add more restriction. Where as currently, any matching Action should pass the test